# How to search an integer field in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want users to be able to search my database using this function:

```
def self.search(query)
  new_query = (query.to_d * 100).to_i
  where("price_in_cents LIKE ?", new_query)
end
```

The problem is that all my `prices` are stored in the database as `integers`, so if someone searches for "10.99" he should *actually* search for "1099".

The function above doesn't work, though, and I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I ended up using this one:

```
def self.search(query)
  string = query.to_s.gsub('.','')
  where("amount_in_cents LIKE ?", "%#{string}%")
end
```

Thanks @grotori for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use "like" for number comparison? You should use either "=" or ">=" etc.

```
def self.search(query)
  new_query = (query.to_d * 100).to_i
  where("price_in_cents = ?", new_query)
end
```

Comment: Yes, good point. You are right actually. The problem is that my search is now a bit too harsh. E.g. if I search for "5", a price of "55" won't be found.

Comment: Then you should create a more complex where statement that will cast your column to string in order to perform "like" comparison.